# paytxfee vs maxtxfee which one overrides the other

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

In wallet options section it shows these two [settings](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin)

```
-paytxfee=<amt>  Fee (in BTC/kB) to add to transactions you send (default: 0.00)  
-maxtxfee=<amt>  Maximum total fees to use in a single wallet transaction, setting too low may abort large transactions (default: 0.10)
```

If I set these two settings in the bitcoin.conf which one will override the other ? or how does in work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is per kilobyte, the other is a limit on the total.

The second will prevent a transaction from happening if it, following the first, has a too large fee.

Comment: Is it possible to pay fixed amount per transaction regardless the kilobytes?

Comment: @Mohamed No, that wouldn't make sense. You're paying for space inside blocks, and miners prioritize transactions based on fee per byte. As you don't know the size of a transaction before creating it, specifying its exact fee would likely lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: https://btc.com/stats/unconfirmed-tx tells you how long your transaction will take to "clear" if you pay a certain transaction fee. Paying 0 may take too long, but you can get away with paying very little if you don't mind a delay in your transaction entering the blockchain.