# how to set the transactions fee using the RPC call?

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, json-rpc

I am creating the web wallet for the bitcoin , I want to allow web wallet users to set the transactions fee .

Is their is any rpc call available for setting the transactions fee (for setting transactions priority) ?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a raw transaction: Inputs - Outputs = Fee. If creating a raw transaction you'll need to calculate this yourself.

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-spending

The link above will provide examples. You use their built in calculation or build your own raw transaction and set whatever fee you like by using Inputs - Outputs. There is no "rpc call" to set it that i can find or have heard of.

You can set variables for WALLETS in the bitcoincore config, but as you stated, you're working on managing multiple wallets for multiple users. Not sure if having bitcoincore manage every one of your wallets for a large number of users is viable or even possible. If i'm wrong, check this out:

[paytxfee vs maxtxfee which one overrides the other](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38957/paytxfee-vs-maxtxfee-which-one-overrides-the-other)

Either way that's not the answer as it's not an "rpc call".

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is ‘estimatesmartfee’ which computes fee with high confirmation probability within n blocks.

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list
I cant see estimatesmartfee rpc call . Please let me know the parameter that is required for this rpc call.

Comment: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/util/estimatesmartfee/

Comment: estimatesmartfee   , i cant see the option to pass the argument for the account , i want to set the fee specific to account name .
As i can understand it will specify the fee for complete wallet. In my case  main wallet has different wallets with different account name or label. With above methods all the accounts have the same transactions fee

Comment: @James C.: OP is asking about setting the fee, not estimating it.

Comment: I misunderstood. Apologies.

Comment: James can you please let me know if there is any RPC method for setting the transaction priority. On the blockchain.com while sending the bitcoin user can set the Transaction fee. Can you please let me know which RPC call they are using for setting the transactions priority

Answer (score 0):

The RPC you're looking for is `settxfee`, which sets the fee per kilo(v)byte.

For example `bitcoin-cli settxfee 0.00027100` is making `bitcoind` use a feerate of 27.1 sat/vbyte for all future transactions.

Comment: This is true and relevant if Bitcoin Core is used a the wallet.
However, in a wallet implementation, where the wallet puts together transactions (collects inputs, selects a subset, performs fee estimation, adds signatures) it is the wallet who deals with these, and the node is used only for broadcasting the transaction.

Comment: @AdamB Yes, the fee rate choice is something to be conveyed to the wallet software you're using. If that's not the Bitcoin Core wallet, you'll need to use the mechanisms that exist for that software instead. The question referred to RPC calls, however, so I assumed the asker was using Bitcoin Core.